# node -v says v4.2.3 but yum install says nothing to do

Tags: node.js, centos, yum

I am trying to install the latest version of `node.js` in my `CentOS 6.9` server.

```
root@server [~]# node -v
v4.2.3
```

my current versions seems to be v4.2.3. I used following line to install new version:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum -y install nodejs
```

it says:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 70.87.220.252
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 70.87.220.252
 * base: dist1.800hosting.com
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: mirror.dal10.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: repo1.dal.innoscale.net
Package 2:nodejs-9.11.1-1nodesource.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

output from `rpm -qa |grep node*`

```
nodesource-release-el6-1.noarch
nodejs-9.11.1-1nodesource.x86_64
```

Comment: can you show us the output from `rpm -qa |grep node*` please. Looks like you have another version (from source maybe) installed but the older version is in the default path. When I search I only get offered `0.10.48` from the `epel` repo.

Comment: I edited my question with output of that code. why is it showing different with `node -v`

Comment: can you do; `whereis node` I suspect you have something in your `/usr/sbin/` or similar path from a base install from code rather than rpm.